# Как грамотно вписать фон в header?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Изучал верстку и наткнулся на проблему. Естть `<header>`, и нужно залить его фоном (2000x1034 пикселей). Как правильно задать размер шапки и `background` для него, чтобы на разных мониторах подстраивался размер?

Comment: Зависит от фона и шапки. Разный рисунок фона будет по смыслу по-разному подстраиваться. Приведите пример здесь.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev фон(2000x1034) как раз таки размером с header, на psd макете. Но мой монитор только 1920x1080 и появляется скроллбар. https://imgur.com/a/XYQVA11

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы размер элемента подстраивался под экран следует указывать его ширину в `%` и высоту в `vh`(высота экрана, `100vh` соответствует высоте равную высоте экрана пользователя). Например, для того, чтобы элемент занимал всю ширину и высоту экрана пользователя не зависимо от разрешения, следует прописать для такого элемента следующие значения: `width:100%;  height: 100vh;`.
Фон для элемента можно задать с помощью свойства `background-image: url(здесь пишем адрес картинки которая нам нужна)` для того, чтобы картинка занимала весь элемент следует прописать свойство `background-size: contain`.

Если у вас изображение не должно занимать полностью весь элемент, но вам нужно ее расположить, скажем по центру, для этого, следует сначала убрать свойство `background-size: contain` и отрегулировать положение изображения в свойстве `bzckground-position: center`, в данном случае изображение будет располагаться по центру элемента.

Также, если хотите лучше контролировать поведение элементов на странице при разном разрешении экрана можно это сделать при помощи:

```css
@media (max-width:700px) and (min-width:481px){
    body{
        background-color: #000;
    }
    
    /* ещё какие-то стили... */

}
```

В этом случае будут применены стили, которые находятся внутри `@media`, только тогда, когда ширина экрана больше `481px` и меньше `700px`. Если надо задать только одну границу(например для любой ширины экрана от `480px` и меньше, то это можно сделать так:

```css
@media (max-width:480px){
    body{
        background-color: #000;
    }
    
    /* ещё какие-то стили... */

}
```